# play and stop sound and changing icon

Tags: python, pygame

Hi so I want to add the typicall icon of sound, and when you click it, it stops and changes to no-sound icon, and when you click it again, it resumes the music, but I don´t know how to. I would like to implement in this code:

```
class Scene(pygame.Surface):
    def __init__(self, next_scene, home_scene):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(screenrect)
        self.next_scene = next_scene
        self.home_scene = home_scene

        # it has the background image and the flecha img so all scenes can use the same background and the flecha img
        self.background_img = background_img 
        self.flechaImg_rect = flechaImg.get_rect()
        self.flechaImg_rect.move_ip(1000,500)  
        self.homeImg_rect = homeImg.get_rect()
        self.homeImg_rect.move_ip(1000,10)
        self.soundImg_rect = soundImg.get_rect()
        self.soundImg_rect.move_ip(1120, 10)
        self.nosoundImg_rect = nosoundImg.get_rect()
        self.nosoundImg_rect.move_ip(1120, 10)



    def get_event(self, event):
        mouse_pos = event.pos
        if self.flechaImg_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            pygame.time.set_timer(fade_event, 1000)
            return self.next_scene
        elif self.homeImg_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            pygame.time.set_timer(fade_event, 1000)
            return self.home_scene
        elif self.soundImg_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
            self.whatsound = "1"


    # there is an update here that does nothing update is called in the main loop and the IntroScene has no updating to do so it would crash otherwise when we tried to call update on the IntroScene (hope that makes sense!)
    def update(self, dt):
        pass

    def draw(self, surf):
        surf.blit(self.background_img, (0,0))
        surf.blit(soundImg, self.soundImg_rect)
```

I´m having struggles because I guess I should be using update to refresh the img it blits but I can´t figure a way. I am using pygame.mixer to play the music, and I know it has a stop, but cant figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute which states if the sound is played:

```py
class Scene(pygame.Surface):
    def __init__(self, next_scene, home_scene):
        # [...]

        self.playing = True
```

Change the current state when the button is clicked:

```py
class Scene(pygame.Surface):
    # [...]

    elif self.soundImg_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        self.whatsound = "1"
        self.playing = not self.playing
```

Draw the icon depending on the state of `playing`:

```py
class Scene(pygame.Surface):
    # [...]

    def draw(self, surf):
        surf.blit(self.background_img, (0,0))

        currentSoundImg = soundImg if self.playing else nosoundImg
        surf.blit(currentSoundImg, self.soundImg_rect)
```